# Maven : Is there a way to check if a particular version of child dependency is compatible with parent?

Tags: maven, cassandra, janusgraph

[image]

I have a `janusgraph-cassandra` dependency in my project which brings `cassandra-all` transitive dependency with it.

Now I am trying to upgrade `cassandra-all` dependency from **2.1.20** to **3.11.4** but it does not seem to be compatible with parent `janusgraph-cassandra` **0.3.1**.

Is there a way to check the version compatibility between parent and transitive dependencies?
Or should it be taken as a rule of thumb that only the versions that a maven artifact brings on it's own are compatible?

Comment: First based on the version change from 2.X to 3.X which is a major version change I would suspect changes...and yes your assumption is from my point of view and experience a good idea..If you need to check otherwise you have to write appropriate tests to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven [`dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) goal is a means to identify where you may have conflicting dependencies, but establishing compatibility is a more complex question that can't be solved by maven on its own.

Establishing whether there is compatibility between versions is sometimes quite difficult.  The primary reason is that there is no enforced rules about what dictates when a library has breaking changes.

A popular way of communicating compatibility is using a predictable versioning strategy.  [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) is one such popular strategy that mandates:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
>
> MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
>
> PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

That being said, `cassandra-all` does not claim to follow this.  Cassandra is a database, and not so much a library.  Between minor versions there are known to be breaking API changes, and I bet it has been known to happen between patch versions.

If you are using janusgraph, I would suggest binding yourself to the version of cassandra that it claims to depend on.

However if you are running janusgraph with cassandra using [Remote Server Mode](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/cassandra.html#_remote_server_mode), I would anticipate that you could upgrade the Cassandra cluster to 3.11.4 and things should continue to work.

It's likely that only when using [Embedded Mode](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/cassandra.html#_janusgraph_embedded_mode) that `cassandra-all` is used.